# Reversing vowels in string in javaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement

This is my code for reversing vowel in a string. I couldnt find what mistake i have done in this..
example:
ip: mobile
op: mebilo

but..
for me..whatever Input i gave, its only being displayed as output.
whats my mistake?
Thank you.

```
const readline = require('readline');
const inp = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin
});
const userInput = [];
  inp.on("line", (data) => {
  userInput.push(data);
});
inp.on("close", () => {
  a= userInput[0];
  b=[];
  n=0;
  for(i=0; i<a.length; i++){
    if(a[i]=="a"||a[i]=="e"||a[i]=="i"||a[i]=="o"||a[i]=="u"){
      b[n]=a[i];
      n+=1;
    }
  }

  last = b.length-1;
  for(j=0; j<a.length; j++){
    if(a[j]=="a"||a[j]=="e"||a[j]=="i"||a[j]=="o"||a[j]=="u"){
      a[j]=b[last];
      last-=1;
    }
  } 
  console.log(a);  
})
```

Comment: Try `console.log(b)` instead of `console.log(a)`

Comment: This is a really good way of solving the problem, by the way. I mean, once you figure out your bug. Well done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a= userInput[0];` & then you do `a[j] = b[last]` this was the issue, you cannot mutate strings in JS.

So change it to `a= userInput[0].split('')` and change console.log to `console.log(a.join(''))`

Example:

```js
function reverseVowels(userInput) {
  a= userInput[0].split('');
  b=[];
  n=0;
  for(i=0; i<a.length; i++){
    if(a[i]=="a"||a[i]=="e"||a[i]=="i"||a[i]=="o"||a[i]=="u"){
      b[n]=a[i];
      n+=1;
    }
  }

  last = b.length-1;
  for(j=0; j<a.length; j++){
    if(a[j]=="a"||a[j]=="e"||a[j]=="i"||a[j]=="o"||a[j]=="u"){
      a[j]=b[last];
      last-=1;
    }
  } 
  console.log(a.join(''));  
}

reverseVowels(['hello']);
```

Comment: a = [...userInput[0]] would be better as it can split Unicode

Answer (score 0):

> `hendrixchord` is right in stating the reason behind the problem you are facing. However, I would extract out a '**isVowel**' logic. This is a slight variation for anyone who lands up here.

```js
const isVowel = item => {
    if (!item) return false
    const chr = item.toLowerCase()
    return chr === 'a' || chr === 'e' || chr === 'i' || chr === 'o' || chr === 'u'
  }

var reverseVowels = function (str) {

  const s = str.split('');

  for (let i = 0, j = s.length - 1; j > i;) {
    if (!isVowel(s[i])) {
      i++
    }
    if (!isVowel(s[j])) {
      j--
    }
    if (isVowel(s[i]) && isVowel(s[j])) {
      let temp = '';
      temp = s[i];
      s[i] = s[j];
      s[j] = temp
      i++;
      j--;
    }
  }

  return s.join('')
};

console.log('reverseVowels', reverseVowels('leetcode'))
```